# assign numeric values from a text to characters in a string using python 2

Tags: python, nlp

if I have a text file contains all english alphabets with some corresponding value like the following:

A   0.00733659550399

B   0.00454138879023

C   0.00279849519224

D   0.00312734304092

.

.

.

I want to assign these numeric values to each line I'm reading from another txt file.

```
L = open(os.path.join(dir, file), "r").read()
            line = L.rstrip()
            tokens = line.split()

            for word in tokens:
                for char in word:
```

find

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the error you're encountering? Also, please indent your code properly.

Comment: Don't iterate over the word. On the word level create a dictionary of form `{a: 0.27373, b: 0.39838}` and so on and then use this dictionary to match your other file.

Comment: input is 'hello' for example: we should assign a numeric value for each letter for 'hello' from a given text file which contains a letter and a corresponding value. output should be 0.04*0.033*0.098*0.08*0.05

Comment: 0.04*0.033*0.098*0.08*0.05 - Then the double "L" should keep the same value right ?

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to assign numeric value for each letter in a string that am reading from a txt file A.txt using another txt file value.txt which contains all english alphabets with corresponding value for each letter. am just mapping the letter values from value.txt to each letter of each word in each line in A.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

**input.txt**

```
AAB BBC ABC
```

**keyvalue.txt**

```
A 123
B 456
C 789
```

**script.py**

```py
def your_func(input_file):
    char_value = {}
    with open('keyvalue.txt', 'r') as f:
        for row in f:
            char_value[row.split()[0]] = row.split()[1]

    res = []
    with open(input_file) as f:
        for row in f:
            for word in row.split():
                for c in word:
                    # Little trick to append only if key exists
                    c in char_value and res.append(char_value[c])
    return '*'.join(res)


print(your_func("input.txt"))

# >>> 123*123*456*456*456*789*123*456*789
```

Comment: I updated my answer to fit author needs : Input is a file, not a word

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary from the first file like this:

```
with open('values.txt') as f:
    values = {k:v for k,v in (line.split() for line in f)}
```

Then iterate over each character of the data file and replace it with the corresponding value:

```
with open('A.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        for c in line.rstrip():
            print(values.get(c.upper(), '0'), file=outfile)
```

This code (assumes Python 3 or import of print function in Python 2) will write to `output.txt` the numeric values corresponding to the input characters, one per line. If there is no value for a character, `0` is output (that can be changed to whatever you want). Note that the incoming characters are converted to upper case because your sample looks like it might comprise upper case letters only. If there are separate values for lower case letters, then you can remove the call to `upper()`.

If you would prefer the values to remain on the same line then you can alter the `print()` function call:

```
with open('A.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        print(*(values.get(c.upper(), '0') for c in line.rstrip()), file=outfile)
```

Now the values will be space separated.

Comment: @BernardMeurer: thanks! You called it in your comment :)

Comment: stuck without a computer right now, can't type good answers on my phone so I just comment the ideas :p